# Constructing SparseTensors from dataset elements and lookup table for estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to create a single tf.SparseTensor to feed into a model. I want to construct a sparse tensor per input then concat them row-wise and then batch them. The inputs are strings which are turned into indices via a lookup table from the contrib.lookup module. The model and input pipeline are constructed via the estimator paradigm and the dataset API. My example protos are in TFRecord files like so:

```
{'user_id': ['user123'],
 'item_id':['item123'],
 'label': [.12]}
```

my `input_fn` looks like this:

```
def dataset_input_fn(tfrecord_pattern, batch_size,
                     n_epochs, user_lookup, item_lookup):

    def _make_sparse_features(features):
        keys_to_features = {
            'user_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.string),
            'item_id': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.string),
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.float32)
         }
        features = tf.parse_single_example(features, keys_to_features)
        user_tensor = sparse_tensor_from_lookup(user_lookup, features['user_id'])

        item_tensor = sparse_tensor_from_lookup(item_lookup, features['item_id'])

        sp_inputs = [user_tensor, item_tensor]
        sparse_features = tf.sparse_concat(axis=0, values=sp_inputs)

        return sparse_features, features['label']

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(glob.glob(tfrecord_pattern))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1028)
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
    dataset = dataset.map(_make_sparse_features)

    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    return dataset
```

where `sparse_tensor_from_lookup` is defined like so (I have tried both `tf.SparseTensor` and `tf.SparseTensorValue`):

```
def sparse_tensor_from_lookup(lookup, key_tensor):
    indices = lookup.lookup(key_tensor)
    sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensorValue(indices=indices,
                                         values=tf.ones_like(indices),
                                         dense_shape=lookup.size())
    return sparse_tensor
```

The lookup tables are instantiated in my `main` training/eval function:

```
def main_training_and_eval_loop(model_function,
                            training_epochs=10000, batch_size=256,
                            max_training_steps=8000000, learning_rate=1e-2, l2_weight=1e-3,
                            reader_n_threads=2, parser_n_threads=2,
                            save_checkpoint_every_n_steps=2000, factor_order=2,
                            max_steps_without_decrease=20000, shuffle_buffer_size=100000,
                            **context):

    model_directory = '/tmp/'

    users_id_file_path = os.path.join(model_directory, 'vocab/users.txt')
    item_id_file_path = os.path.join(model_directory, 'vocab/items.txt')

    tfrecord_dir = 'airflow_tmp/tfrecords_backfill_2018-09-29T00:43:32.624007/'

    item_lookup = index_table_from_file(item_id_file_path,
                                              num_oov_buckets=1)
    user_lookup = index_table_from_file(users_id_file_path,
                                     num_oov_buckets=1)

    training_input_fn = functools.partial(dataset_input_fn,
                                          os.path.join(tfrecord_dir, '*.tfrecord'), 
                                          batch_size=batch_size,
                                          n_epochs=training_epochs,
                                          user_lookup=user_lookup,
                                          item_lookup=item_lookup)


... etc
```

The error I receive seems to be with regard to the values being passed to `tf.SparseTensor` when trying to construct said tensor:

```
<ipython-input-5-ec313e9d7732> in _make_sparse_features(features)
 17         }
 18         features = tf.parse_single_example(features, keys_to_features)
---> 19         course_tensor = sparse_tensor_from_lookup(course_lookup, features['target_course_id'])
     20 
     21         course_tags = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features['course_tags'], default_value='')

~/Code/learning-recommendations/airflow/dags/utils/tensorflow/sparse.py in sparse_tensor_from_lookup(lookup, key_tensor)
      6     sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices,
      7                                     values=tf.ones_like(indices),
----> 8                                     dense_shape=lookup.size())
      9     return sparse_tensor

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py in __init__(self, indices, values, dense_shape)
    132     self._dense_shape = dense_shape
    133 
--> 134     indices_shape = indices.get_shape().with_rank(2)
    135     values_shape = values.get_shape().with_rank(1)
    136     dense_shape_shape = dense_shape.get_shape().with_rank(1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in with_rank(self, rank)
    745       return self.merge_with(unknown_shape(ndims=rank))
    746     except ValueError:
--> 747       raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
    748 
    749   def with_rank_at_least(self, rank):

ValueError: Shape (1,) must have rank 2
```

but this differs from the error I get with `tf.SparseTensorValue`:

```
<ipython-input-5-ec313e9d7732> in _make_sparse_features(features)
     30 
     31         sp_inputs = [course_tensor, course_tags_tensor, user_tensor, user_interests_tensor]
---> 32         sparse_features = tf.concat(axis=0, values=sp_inputs)
     33 
     34         return sparse_features, features['label']

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in concat(values, axis, name)
   1112               tensor_shape.scalar())
   1113       return identity(values[0], name=scope)
-> 1114   return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1115 
   1116 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py in concat_v2(values, axis, name)
   1028     _attr_N = len(values)
   1029     _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper(
-> 1030         "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
   1031     _result = _op.outputs[:]
   1032     _inputs_flat = _op.inputs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(self, op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    481                                 (prefix, dtype.name))
    482               else:
--> 483                 raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
    484             else:
    485               raise TypeError("%s that are invalid." % prefix)

TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [<NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>, <NOT CONVERTIBLE TO TENSOR>] that don't all match.
```

Am I off the res here? I've struggled to find materials on how to work this kind of workflow with the dataset api and an even harder time finding material on the differences between `tf.SparseTensor` and `tf.SparseTensorValue` or much info on sparse tensors at all.